# SD Card protection - Access by key

Tags: android, security, cryptography, storage, fingerprint

I am in a trouble about making my SD card secure.
I want to encrypt some of data (or all data) in my SD Card.
This data can be access by using Fingerprint, Irris, Gesture, Pin, Password, or any authetication method in Android (will be updated to iOS and PC). When I have the previledge to access to the data, I can copy (remove) new data to (from) the storage. When I do not in the SD card, data will be encrypted behind the scene.
The requirement is acceptable encryption/decryption speed and highly secure.

Do you have any solution (framework, api, ...) or suggestion that can help me go faster in this project?

Thank all in advance and I also apologize if there's any mistake from my question.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

If you use java maybe [this](https://github.com/mrpdaemon/encfs-java) or [this](https://github.com/mrpdaemon/encdroid) or [this](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=starn/encdroidMC/encdroidMC-master/src/org/mrpdaemon/sec/encfs/EncFSVolume.java) helps you.

---

**Obsolete answer**

I have not used it but you may take a look at VeraCrypt. I'm sure you'll find some android apps that can handle veracrypt containers. Disadvantage (afaik): It creates an encrypted container file of fixed(?) size.

If you use Linux you also could take account of encfs file system. In this case each file would be encrypted separately. It is [available](http://members.ferrara.linux.it/freddy77/encfs.html) for windows. There might be apps for android. Take a look at BoxCryptor Classic. I've used this to encrypt/decrypt files in a dropbox directory.

Comment: Sorry but I need a solution to build an app, that can be a framework, api,...

Comment: I updated my answer. Please be more specific in your question the next time.